# Disable duplicate check for apex trigger?

Tags: trigger

I have an issue where in Duplicate Rule(Alert) on contact  is blocking creation of contact , so issue is that a Trigger which is part of managed package is tripping because of Duplicate Rule Alert , any idea how can we disable duplicate check for apex trigger??

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use the [DuplicateRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm) to suppress errors. However, if you do not own the trigger logic, only your vendor can fix this problem; you will need to speak to them about it. There;s no way you can fix this without them.